# How to use a linear block code algorithm while also checking for a polynomial generator in matlab

Tags: matlab

I tried creating a function to encode a vector message using Linear block Code Algorithm entered by the user and while checking if there is a generator polynomial G(x) rather than a generator matrix G binary.
this is the code I tried but it always crash for some reason

```
for i = 1:K
s=sprintf('Enter 1 if order %d exist in your decoder 0 if not exist ',i);
t=input(s,'s');
while  (strcmp(t,'0')== 0 && strcmp(t,'1')== 0)


 display('Error value only 0 or 1 Enter 1')
s=sprintf('if order %d exist in your generator 0 if not exist ',i);
t=input(s,'s');
end
```

Comment: I see no evidence that this question is about MATLAB GUI development or integration of MATLAB code with other languages. Please choose your tags more carefully.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Then [edit] your question with a [mcve]. This code won't even run, as you're at least missing an `end` to close off the `for` loop. Also please add the definitions we need (e.g. `K`), and what "crash" means (errors, warnings, incorrect results, exploding computers...).